# Python Google App Engine: How to move SearchResults data into my template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm finishing up a project, and I have run into a snag using python on google app engine.
I have an app that keeps note entries. I would like to be able to search these entries, and I am using this link:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

I am able to save documents, search them, delete them, etc. Everything is working, but I can't see any info on how to parse the SearchResults into a template.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: 0% accepted questions? Sort that out before anyone will help you.

Comment: I am not even sure what that means. I have had questions answered here.

Also, pushing someone out of the community is a bad way to continue your community. Maybe someone else will have less of a chip on their shoulder and answer, if you want to point me in a direction, it would be much appreciated. If you just want to look at a number on the screen and make a judgement, then I'm sure you can find better things to do.

Comment: I agree, not participating does hurt the community. I have clicked up on answers before, I thought that was all there was to it. I will look for how to "accept" and answer and start doing that from here on in. Sorry for my frustration.

Comment: Got it. I have to click the check button, not just the up arrow. Will go back and do this.

Comment: looks like you still didn't do it on this post ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way to do is to use the entity keys as keys for the search documents.

```
doc = search.Document(doc_id=<entity_key_as_string>, fields=fields)
```

then make the search query and return only the entity keys:

```
options = search.QueryOptions(ids_only=True)
query   = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
```

and then get the entities from the datastore and render the template.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll give that a shot when I get back around to that part of the code.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, it seems orthogonal as to whether you're associating datastore entities with your search documents (though this can often be useful to do). You don't need an entity to render the document info in a template.

You can access the document fields in a template along these lines:

```
  {% for field in doc.fields %}
      {{field.name}}&nbsp;{{field.value}} <br/>
  {% endfor %}
```

Or with jinja2, get a specific field value like this:

```
{{doc.field("yourfieldname").value}}
```

Comment: so you can access document fields by name? didn't know that. is it documented?

Comment: The 'field' method of Document was added recently, and it looks like it's not yet properly documented.  We'll fix that for the next release.